# How to run multiple cucumber tags in order?

Tags: automation, cucumber

I have 3 feature files I need to run which includes login, any feature file, logout. My tags listed are: @login, @feature, @logout. When I run the automation, @logout runs before @feature. How do I make it so it completes in the order that is li

Since the tags are in order and a ',' means OR, I thought it would complete in order since with 2 features - @login, @feature, it runs in order but when adding the 3rd tag it runs that before the second